# How to make custom modal uiview like this?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uialertview

I need some modal view on iPhone app where I will display few labels, one UIImageView and two buttons. Design needs to be whole custom. 
Is this custom UIAlertView? How to make something similar?

[image: UIView in Tweetboot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a nice blog post by Jeff LaMarche about how to create a custom Alert View. You can take inspiration from there.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html

** UPDATE on April 24, 2017 **
Unfortunately the blog doesn't exist anymore. However you can retrieve the post from the Web Archive:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160430051146/http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html

Comment: Really nice post, thanks. I must to read it to figure out what is the best solution for my situation

Comment: Sadly this blog post is no longer available

Comment: Added link to web archive.

Answer (score 2):

See the source for [Tapku](http://tapku.com/) library. They have this option - you can always hack/tweak source code for it. Its not that difficult though, Just a lot of layer magic going around (e.g. the vignette effect). and most of the assets are images. You just need to break it down properly.

Comment: I will give them a try, thks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can acquire that simply following the following steps

1. Create UIview (ViewA)of size 320*480 , so that it will cover whole screen of iPhone with  background set to clearColor.This will serve as super view for our purpose;
2. Create another UIView (ViewB) of size 320*480 with background color set to black and opacity to 40%.
   3.Now you can add any view on ViewB.
3. Now add ViewB to ViewA.

Finally you can Present this view where ever required. The effect will be, ViewA will cover the Background viewController, ViewB will server as suppressing effect for background view controller and views on B are the UIElement you will see.

Answer (score 1):

Making a view like this is simple.  You just need to create a custom view with the pieces that you want and just make it hidden or set the alpha to 0.0.  Then un-hide it when you want to use it.

To prevent interaction with other items behind the view put a blank semi-transparent view right behind your custom view.

Answer (score 0):

```
        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\Please wait. \n Authorising Credentials..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];   
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 40, 40)];
        NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"smile.png"]];
        UIImage *bkgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [imageView setImage:bkgImg];
        [bkgImg release];
        [path release];
        [alert addSubview:imageView];
        [imageView release];
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
        [alert show];
```

Comment: I need more customized view. Thx